# In Java Swing Null Layout, set position relative to bottom of container

Tags: java, swing, overriding, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

This is probably a very basic question, but I could't find anything about it online.

I'm working in Java swing and have a JPanel with a null Layout Manager (ie using absolute positioning).  The JPanel is filling a space in the JFrame so that its size will change when the JFrame is resized.  Within this JPanel, I have a number of other components that I have placed using `Component.setBounds()`.  I would like one of these components to be set relative to the bottom of the JPanel, so that when the containing JPanel resizes, the smaller JComponent stays stuck to the bottom of the container.

I have tried to do this by overriding the `getLocation()` or `getBounds()` methods to reference the container height, but neither of these seemed to work the way overriding `getPreferredSize()` would, even after calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()`.  Unfortunately, using another layout manager like BorderLayout is not an option here.

Is there a way to do something like this?  Am I missing something obvious?  If not, is there a way to listen for changes in the container's height and re-call `.setBounds()`?

Comment: *"I would like one of these components to be set relative to the bottom of the JPanel, so that when the containing JPanel resizes, the smaller JComponent stays stuck to the bottom of the container."* Layout managers will do this for you trivially. If you want relative positioning, then you shouldn't be using absolute positioning.

Comment: Just don't use `null` layout and all your problems will be solved. Every screen and graphics environment is different and `null` layout does not accommodate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try listening to the resize event of the panel:

```
panel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            component.setBounds(...);

        }
    });
```

You can reference `panel.getBounds` from withing this method and set your components bounds accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can add a component listener to your JFrame.

```
addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
        //Do stuff here
    }
});
```

Inside the component listener you can change the sizes and locations of anything you would like to.  To stick them to the bottom simply get the size of the JFrame and subtract a specific amount and set that as the y location for what you want stuck to the bottom.